# how to remove some css attributes defined by bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I  am using bootstrap,however I found some problems if I want to delete some css styles defined by bootstrap.

For example,there is a style by bootstrap:

```
img{
    max-height:100%;    
}
```

Now,how about if I want to remove this attribute?

I have tried this:

```
img{
    max-height:"";
}
```

It seems that this does not work.

So I use javascript instead:

```
$("img").each(function(){
    $(this).css("maxWidth","");
});
```

Any other good idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `max-height:none` (the [initial value for `max-height`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/max-height)) and make sure this is declared below the bootstrap css file.

```
img{
    max-height:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you are modifying the correct .css file, you could be modifying the incorrect one. Bootstrap has multiple CSS files, if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 0):

[max height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/max-height)'s default value is `none`, not empty quotes.